# How to add mysql driver jar to project as dependancy to github repo?

Tags: java, mysql, github, maven-3

So as the title implies, how do I add a dependancy (in this case mysql jdbc driver) to my java project on github ?  I am thinking of moving all my files over and creating a maven project since it appears a lot easier to include external dependencies in the pom.

Comment: I agree creating a maven project is the easiest way to include external dependencies. All you have to do is just add the dependency in your pom and you get the jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for Oracle JDBC

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

If you want to use the standard java jdbc just import it.

```
import java.sql.*;
```

It is inside the java apialready and you don't want anything else (not maven, not gradle).

Here is how to use it.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

If you want to just start using maven to learn it I suggest to download the Intellij community edition and start a new maven project. You will get a maven ready project.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: I already know how to use the jdbc.  Locally on my computer I have the mysql driver, I was just wondering the best way to include the driver jar file in the github project.  It seems maven is my best bet.

Comment: You don't need to include. It is inside the java jars

Comment: But when i download the project from github and open it in netbeans it doesn't include the mysql-connector-java-5.136-bin.jar which is necessary for the project to interact with mysql.

Comment: So you are not working with the java jdbc but with the mysql-connector-java. You need to copy the jar to the libs folder, add it to the classpath, add it to the git index and push it to github

Comment: in my current project I have the jar in the libs folder and is in classpath.  Should I actually add a libs folder to github containing the jar ?

Comment: The simple answer is yes if you want to do just the job

Comment: Would this then be added to the libs when the project is opened in netbeans after its cloned from github ?

Comment: If you set up the classpath the correct way, yes